# Cross compiling scipy for open-embedded

Tags: python, scipy, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I'm currently trying to corss-compile scipy for open-embedded but the bitbake build failed with the error

```
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: python-scipy-1.0.0-r0 do_compile: python setup.py build execution failed.
ERROR: python-scipy-1.0.0-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/somewhere_in_my_home_folder/build_dir/tmp/work/core2-64-idp-linux/python-scipy/1.0.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.2788)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/somewhere_in_my_home_folder/build_dir/tmp/work/core2-64-idp-linux/python-scipy/1.0.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.2788
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| Traceback (most recent call last):
|   File "setup.py", line 418, in <module>
|     setup_package()
|   File "setup.py", line 398, in setup_package
|     from numpy.distutils.core import setup
| ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core
| ERROR: python setup.py build execution failed.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/somewhere_in_my_home_folder/build_dir/tmp/work/core2-64-idp-linux/python-scipy/1.0.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.2788)
ERROR: Task (/home/somewhere_in_my_home_folder/recipes-ros/python-scipy/python-scipy_1.0.0.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
```

I already spend searching several hours for recipe which works, but without any success. The only thing I found about this error was [here](https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-dev/2016-July/021411.html).

My recipe looks like this

```
DESCRIPTION = "SciPy"
SECTION = "devel/python"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

PYPI_PACKAGE = "scipy"
inherit pypi setuptools distutils

DEPENDS_${PN} = "python-numpy python-setuptools python-distutils"
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "python-numpy python-setuptools python-distutils"

S = "${WORKDIR}/scipy-1.0.0"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "53fa34bd3733a9a4216842b6000f7316"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "87ea1f11a0e9ec08c264dc64551d501fa307289460705f6fccd84cbfc7926d10"
```

Any ideas on how to crosscompile scipy oder on how to fix this error?

edit 1:

my changed my recipe to

```
DESCRIPTION = "SciPy"
SECTION = "devel/python"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

PYPI_PACKAGE = "scipy"

DEPENDS_${PN} = "python-numpy python-setuptools python-distutils"
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "python-numpy python-setuptools python-distutils"

S = "${WORKDIR}/scipy-1.0.0"

PACKAGECONFIG[python2] = "-DPYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/numpy/core/include,,python-numpy,"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "53fa34bd3733a9a4216842b6000f7316"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "87ea1f11a0e9ec08c264dc64551d501fa307289460705f6fccd84cbfc7926d10"

FILES_python-scipy+="/usr/lib/* /usr/lib/python2.7/*"
FILES_python-scipy-dev+="/usr/share/pkgconfig   /usr/lib/pkgconfig   /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/*.la "
FILES_python-scipy-staticdev+="/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/*.a "

inherit pypi ${@bb.utils.contains('PACKAGECONFIG', 'python2', 'distutils-base', '', d)}
```

but now I get a error while building the main image

```
No package python-scipy available.
Error: Unable to find a match
```

Comment: opencv recipe uses this line: `PACKAGECONFIG[python2] = "-DPYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/numpy/core/include,,python-numpy,"` Maybe you need to add this include folder in `EXTRA_OECONF` ?

Comment: Thank you, I also added `inherit ${@bb.utils.contains('PACKAGECONFIG', 'python2', 'distutils-base', '', d)}` and now the build works. But after adding it to `IMAGE_INSTALL` as a dependency in my core image the build of the core image build complains `No package python-scipy available. Error: Unable to find a match`. But I can build the scipy recipe with `bitbake python-scipy`

Comment: it probably means you don't have put any file into package, and as ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} should be unset, it removes the package. You must add installed files to package by setting FILES_${PN} += "..."

Comment: I updated my recipe in this post. I checked the difference between all `FILES` var's of both recipes with `bitbake -e` and added the differences. Still the same error. Actually I don't have any ideas what I need to add there or how to find this out.

Comment: did you manage to compile it?

Comment: no ... our solution is to manualy install scipy via pip after we installed the image on the device :-(. I tried to debug it but my python and OE knowledge is not as substantial as it is needed

Comment: So far I dont understand the problem actuallay, because for all our python projects the content is just copied nothing needs to be compiled. And as far I understand numpy is the only lib which is required and this is actuallay build properly by bitbake ... so no idea whats wrong there

Answer (score 0):

That kind of recipe should be enough to get SciPy to work:

```
SUMMARY = "Scientific Library for Python"
SECTION = "devel/python"
HOMEPAGE = "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy"

LICENSE = "BSD-3-Clause"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE.txt;md5=d0db8f4148a3d5534cfb93be78f9287c"

PYPI_PACKAGE="scipy"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "53fa34bd3733a9a4216842b6000f7316"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "87ea1f11a0e9ec08c264dc64551d501fa307289460705f6fccd84cbfc7926d10"

inherit pypi setuptools distutils

RDEPENDS_${PN} += "python-core python-numpy python-distutils"
DEPENDS += "python-numpy"
```

If it fails, you can try to replace 
`DEPENDS += "python-numpy"` by `DEPENDS += "python-numpy-native"`. And if it still fails, you should create an issue on SciPy [github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues) or try to patch setup files, you can see an example [here](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python/python-matplotlib/fix_setupext.patch).

Comment: Thank you @Nayfe for you effort. But it is still failing with the mentioned error msg. I looked into the setup.py and saw that the import form `numpy` works but not the one importing `numpy.distutils.core`. I also tried finding out more in the devshell but everything look good there. I'll create an issue on SciPy github. Hopefully they fell responsible for this issue :-)